# How to check if the following files are exists are not with condition in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I had an scenario

In this path $path1 i have list of files

```
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL6.DEBUG.i386.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL6.DEBUG.x86_64.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL6.i386.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL6.x86_64.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL7.DEBUG.x86_64.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.RHEL7.x86_64.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.SLES12SP4.DEBUG.x86_64.rpm
 LINUX-7.1.0.00.00-010.SLES12SP4.x86_64.rpm
```

In $path2 i have these files
7.1.0.00.00-010 - (build.major).(build.minor).(build.servicepack).(build.patch).(build.hotfix)-(build.number)

```
  build.major       - 7
  build.minor       - 1
  build.servicepack - 0
  build.patch       - 0
  build.hotfix      - 0
  build.number      - 010
```

I need to check if List of particular files exists or not, if exists then it can follow some steps else it should exit.

Comment: Concatenate all the values from $path2 with the appropriate delimiters between them, and then use `grep -F` to search for it in `$path1`.

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar said, this website is more aimed at solving technical issues.
Assuming you don't know where to look, I would approach the problem with the following steps:

- "cat" the input file and use "awk" to extract the 3rd column
- use the output in a for loop to iterate through the lines (even if you could do it with awk directly), concatenating in a variable (called tmp for example)
- looking for the files using $tmp in their name.

So, in shell, you can use awk to select a column from a text input, you can iterate directly through lines of a text flux with a for loop and you can insert the value of a variable in a string, using $myVariable.

You're now on tracks!